# Submit form data with button that does not have type submit

Tags: jquery, ajax, coldfusion

I am trying to submit form data to create session variables from a button that does not have a submit type (because it is pre-made). I was trying to do this using ajax.

The button is created like this:

```
<a aria-controls="processing" tabindex="0" id="ToolTables_processing_1" class="DTTT_button DTTT_button_pdf"><span>PDF</span></a>
```

I try to create a form submit and ajax call like this:

```
$('#ToolTables_processing_1').on('click', function () {
            $.ajax({
                // the location of the CFC to run
                url: "redirects/selectedrows.cfm",
                // send a GET HTTP operation
                type: "post",
                // tell jQuery we're getting JSON back
                dataType: "json",
                // send the data to the CFC
                 data: $('#form').serialize(),
                // this gets the data returned on success
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    //window.location = 'forms/exitinterviewpdf.cfm';
                }, 
                // this runs if an error
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    // show error
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                }
            });
        });
```

But the form just submits and does not carryout the ajax call. If I remove `$('#form').submit();` I get this error: [image]

[image]

my redirects/selectedrows.cfm

```
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowName = form.selectedRowName >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowtodayDate = form.selectedRowtodayDate >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowtitle = form.selectedRowtitle >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowdepartment = form.selectedRowdepartment >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowhireDate = form.selectedRowhireDate >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowterminationDate = form.selectedRowterminationDate >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowreasonLeaving = form.selectedRowreasonLeaving >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowfeelPay = form.selectedRowfeelPay >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowprogressHere = form.selectedRowprogressHere >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowanotherJob = form.selectedRowanotherJob >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowcomparewith = form.selectedRowcomparewith >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowhigherSalary = form.selectedRowhigherSalary >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowpreventLeaving = form.selectedRowpreventLeaving >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowclearlyExplained = form.selectedRowclearlyExplained >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowbyWhom = form.selectedRowbyWhom >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowadequateTraining = form.selectedRowadequateTraining >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowworkPerform = form.selectedRowworkPerform >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowworkingCondition = form.selectedRowworkingCondition >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowsalary = form.selectedRowsalary >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowretirement = form.selectedRowretirement >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowhealthPlan = form.selectedRowhealthPlan >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowtuition = form.selectedRowtuition >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowunileave = form.selectedRowunileave >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowcoworkers = form.selectedRowcoworkers >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowsupervisionReceived = form.selectedRowsupervisionReceived >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowneededHelp = form.selectedRowneededHelp >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowmanagerRespond = form.selectedRowmanagerRespond >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowsuggestionsBetterPlace = form.selectedRowsuggestionsBetterPlace >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowrealReasonForLeaving = form.selectedRowrealReasonForLeaving >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowcomments = form.selectedRowcomments >

<cfoutput>#SerializeJSON(session.exitinterview.selected)#</cfoutput>
```

**form fields**

```
<form id="form" name="form">
<input id="selectedRowName" name="selectedRowName" type="text"/>
<input name="selectedRowtodayDate" id="selectedRowtodayDate" type="text"/>
<input id="selectedRowtitle" name="selectedRowtitle" type="text"/>
<input id="selectedRowdepartment" name="selectedRowdepartment" type="text"/>
<input id="selectedRowhireDate" name="selectedRowhireDate" type="text"/>
<input id="selectedRowterminationDate" name="selectedRowterminationDate" type="text"/>
<input id="selectedRowreasonLeaving" name="selectedRowreasonLeaving" type="text"/>
<input id="selectedRowfeelPay" name="selectedRowfeelPay" type="text"/>
<input id="selectedRowprogressHere" name="selectedRowprogressHere" type="text"/>
<input id="selectedRowanotherJob" name="selectedRowanotherJob" type="text"/>
<input id="selectedRowcomparewith" name="selectedRowcomparewith" type="text"/>
<input id="selectedRowhigherSalary" name="selectedRowhigherSalary" type="text"/>
<input id="selectedRowpreventLeaving" name="selectedRowpreventLeaving" type="text"/>
<input id="selectedRowclearlyExplained" name="selectedRowclearlyExplained" type="text"/>
<input id="selectedRowbyWhom" name="selectedRowbyWhom" type="text"/>
<input id="selectedRowadequateTraining" name="selectedRowadequateTraining" type="text"/>
<input id="selectedRowworkPerform" name="selectedRowworkPerform" type="text"/>
<input id="selectedRowworkingCondition" name="selectedRowworkingCondition" type="text"/>
<input id="selectedRowsalary" name="selectedRowsalary" type="text"/>
<input id="selectedRowretirement" name="selectedRowretirement" type="text"/>
<input id="selectedRowhealthPlan" name="selectedRowhealthPlan" type="text"/>
<input id="selectedRowtuition" name="selectedRowtuition" type="text"/>
<input id="selectedRowunileave" name="selectedRowunileave" type="text"/>
<input id="selectedRowcoworkers" name="selectedRowcoworkers" type="text"/>
<input id="selectedRowsupervisionReceived" name="selectedRowsupervisionReceived" type="text"/>
<input id="selectedRowneededHelp" name="selectedRowneededHelp" type="text"/>
<input id="selectedRowmanagerRespond" name="selectedRowmanagerRespond" type="text"/>
<input id="selectedRowsuggestionsBetterPlace" name="selectedRowsuggestionsBetterPlace" type="text"/>
<input id="selectedRowrealReasonForLeaving" name="selectedRowrealReasonForLeaving" type="text"/>
<input id="selectedRowcomments" name="selectedRowcomments" type="text"/>
</form>
```

**For a better visual of whats going on**
[image]

In chrome error:
[image]

[image]

**firefox post items**
[image]

Or maybe is there a way to just pass the values of my object thats created in the console?

If I remove `datatype:json` I end up getting an empty string...[image]

Comment: What is the problem ?

Comment: You forgot to mention the problem.

Comment: Shouldn't the submit take place after the ajax call?

Comment: even moving the submit above the window.location still throws the same error posted above

Comment: `If I remove $('#form').submit(); I get this error` So your server doesn't return json formated object. Remove `dataType: "json",` and check what data you get. Or better, debug it from your network tab or server log

Comment: it does i have this working on another project the only difference is that the button has a submit type on the other one

Comment: @DavidBrierton I'm sure it does not, maybe jsonp... I could be completly wrong of course

Comment: im telling u it does i have this exact thing on another application

Comment: maybe the problems are on the redirect page then

Comment: Try changing the data type to `application/json`.

Comment: @Ciprianis No conversion from text to application/json error

Comment: @DavidBrierton `im telling u it does i have this exact thing on another application` BUT the error message suggests it doesn't...

Comment: What if you change your code to `<cfcontent type="text/json"><cfoutput>#SerializeJSON(session.exitinterview.selected)#</cfoutput>`?

Comment: the ending cfoutput is a different color is there an error in it?

Comment: Also could you ensure that nothing is being output other than `#SerializeJSON( ... )#`.

Comment: @PeterKA nothing else is those are the only things on that cfm but for some reason the ending cfoutput is a different color very strange ill post a picture

Comment: What is the purpose to `cfcontent` here? What if you remove it?

Comment: i only added it for peter

Comment: @DavidBrierton Ok i'm sorry.

Comment: ughhhh why is this so difficult i have a datatable when u select a row all the database info get inserted into hidden fields im just trying to take these hidden fields and turn them into session variables.. this does not make sense of why this is so difficult

Comment: Color all depends on what IDE you're using. It may be that you have a syntax error and therefore your outut is an error rather than the object. I would recommend a `cftry/cfcatch` but that would probably catch runtime errors only.

Comment: i fixed the color but still did not do anything

Comment: All i want to do is take the textboxes and turn the form variables into session variables does anyone have any suggestions in how i can do this :/ since this is not working

Comment: should i be using get or post?

Comment: @PeterKA Any ideas if I remove datatype:json its just an empty string

Comment: @A.Wolff Any ideas if I remove datatype:json its just an empty string

Answer (score 1):

In the moment you make the submit call the page is expecting be redirected by the controller, so the code after *form.submit()* wont be executed.

But you can make the call by ajax and continue with some other tasks:

```
$('#ToolTables_processing_1').on('click', function (e) {
            $.ajax({
                // the location of the CFC to run
                url: "/pageToProcessTheForm",
                // send a GET HTTP operation
                type: "post",
                // send the data to the CFC
                 data: $('#form').serialize(),
                // this gets the data returned on success
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    //here you add all the business logic needed according to the server response
                    window.location = 'forms/exitinterviewpdf.cfm';
                }, 
                // this runs if an error
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    // show error
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: @DavidBrierton I removed from my response the dataType=json, actually you are not sending a json format data, just a serialized form. Also you need to response from your controller with a ResponseBody annotation to return a json object to the ajax call

Comment: @cralfaro dataType is `The type of data that you're expecting back from the server`. It is different than contentType: `When sending data to the server, use this content type.`

Comment: when i removed it is says empty string in the console log

Comment: @A.Wolff I posted the code above from the other project to show u it does use json

Comment: I dunno i am so confused now its just an empty string its like the form variables are not carrying over

Comment: @DavidBrierton and sure there is a form with the ID=form?

Comment: @DavidBrierton what error are you getting now? the data goes to the controller?

Comment: when i remove datatype it just says empty string when datatype is json i get `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`

Comment: and if you inspect the response from your browser, can you check is a well formed json? you can check it with firebug or some other tool in network option. Maybe the value from the controller is not JSON well formed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112810/discussion-between-david-brierton-and-cralfaro).

Comment: @cralfaro do you know why if i remove the datatype why I would just get an empty string?

Comment: @cralfaro what do you mean the chat is blocked?

Comment: @cralfaro Any ideas if I remove datatype:json its just an empty string

Comment: @DavidBrierton in your controller's method what kind of data are you returning? if you are using spring, remember to add the annotation ResponseBody to translate to json format

Comment: I am not sure what you mean im pretty new to coding :(

Comment: In your controller you will have a POST method where receive the data from the view (jsp) then this method should return some value, that object is the one will be transformed to json and read into success callaback if your ajax call.